# Remove 302 temporary redirect

Tags: website, iis, redirection

I have a site that goes from `https://example.com` (301 Permanent Redirect) to `https://example.com` (301 Permanent Redirect) to `http://www.example.com` (302 Temporary Redirect) to `https://www.example.com` (Final Destination).

How do I remove `http://www.example.com` (302 Temporary Redirect)?

Comment: This all depends on your configuration. It seems like your site is trying to force HTTPS but also redirect all traffic from the hot root to `www.`; this is really specific to your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located a rule in IIS under the default site (URL Rewrite) and changed the redirect from http to https.